# How can i get device information and browser information in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to detect if the user is logged in a new device or in a new browser. From browser i can get navigator info. But how to find if its a different browser or device.

Answer (score 0):

You should store a cookie or use the localStorage API to track users, or use a more robust authentication system that handles it.